# Interactive, Selectable and scrollable Items in Console Application in .NET Core like Yeoman console

Tags: c#, console-application, yeoman, interactive, .net-core

Does anybody have an idea about how create Intractive and selectable items in Console ?

When you install yeoman as node.js package and call it from command line with 'yo',

They show us a list of scrollable items that can choose with up down arrow keys.

Is there anyway for this purpose any code or library ? (in .NET Core)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The console isn't really meant to be interactive.  In recent versions (Windows 10, Server 2012 R2) the console is a bit more user friendly, but interactions are still like most other terminals: typing in and pressing enter.  For what you want, see about slapping a multi-line textblock of some sort onto a windows form/wpf form and formatting accordingly.

Comment: @jdl134679 so How Yeoman have that and works successfully ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They key parts of the solution are:

- You can use `Console.ReadKey()` to detect pressing of arrow keys
- You can use `Console.CursorTop` to read and write the current cursor position

Using those two, here is a very simple code that does what you want:

```
int optionsCount = 5;

int selected = 0;

bool done = false;

while (!done)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < optionsCount; i++)
    {
        if (selected == i)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.Write("> ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("  ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(i);

        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
            selected = Math.Max(0, selected - 1);
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
            selected = Math.Min(optionsCount - 1, selected + 1);
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.Enter:
            done = true;
            break;
    }

    if (!done)
        Console.CursorTop = Console.CursorTop - optionsCount;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Selected {selected}.");
```